# How to send/receive URL parameters in a HTTP POST correctly?

Tags: python, cakephp, http-post, python-requests

I am using cakephp 2.4.5. I want to send a HTTP POST with URL parameters. I am using python 2.7 request module to send the HTTP POST. Please assume the payload is structured correctly as I have tested that part.

```
URL_post = http://127.0.0.1/webroot/TestFunc?identity_number=S111A/post
r = requests.post(URL_post, payload)
```

On the cakephp side, the controller looks something like this;

```
public function TestFunc($id=null)
{
    $identity_number = $this->request->query['identity_number'];  
    $this->request->data['Model']['associated_id']=$identity_number;
    $this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));   
}
```

I have tested that the query is not received correctly. However, if I am not using HTTP POST and just throwing in a normal URL, the query can be received correctly.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if your value is inside `$this->request->data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query part of the url is sent correctly:

```
import requests

requests.post('http://localhost/webroot/TestFunc?identity_number=S111A/post',
              {'Model': 'data'})
```

#### The Request

```
POST /webroot/TestFunc?identity_number=S111A/post HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/3.4 Linux/3.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 10

Model=data
```

You could also make the requests using `params`:

```
requests.post('http://localhost/webroot/TestFunc',
              data={'Model': 'data'},
              params={'identity_number': 'S111A/post'})
```

The only difference is that `S111A/post` is sent as `S111A%2Fpost` (the same url in the end).

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls.

```
payload = {"identity_number": "S111A/post"}
URL_post = "http://127.0.0.1/webroot/TestFunc"
req = requests.post(URL_post, params=payload)
print(req.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the answer did not work. From the link, it seems the parameters were for HTTP GET, not HTTP POST. Is it a limitation that HTTP POST cannot send parameters in URL?

Comment: It is the same for both.